# How to redirect to a specific page on click of app icon?

Tags: ios, cordova

We are working on iPhone app and we have implemented push notification functionality. When the app is inactive, any notification received shows an alert and the badge icon counter gets incremented. When the user clicks either on the app's icon or on the alert, the app becomes active and everything works fine.

What we want is this: On new notification, whenever a user clicks on the app icon, it should open a specific page (e.g. the *Notifications* page). Currently, when the app becomes active, it shows the last previously open page.

How can I redirect the app (on foreground) to a specific page?

Answer (score 1):

assume that this is your `PayLoad`

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Hai User","type":"center","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```

the **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method handle the **payload**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    // this is used for clear the count when user press the notification.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];


  //When notification is pressed on background it comes here

  //Get strings based on information on your json payload for example

    NSMutableString *notificationType =[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]objectForKey:@"type"];

  if([notificationType isEqualToString:@"center"]){
       //redirect/push a viewcontroler here , it automatically navigate to your VC.

       profileViewController *profile = [[profileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"profile ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: profile animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }
}
```

notification types from Apple is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: need more reference redirect to particular page use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807503/open-view-controller-when-apns-is-received-in-ios)

Comment: actually my answer is related to when user clicked the notification it redirect/open the particular page.

Comment: Can you explain us last 2 lines of code. We are new to this objective c, and in our app notification is an html page.

Comment: sry bro I write down the code for iOS , plz refer this link https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/213

Comment: How can I call javascript function in my appdelegate.m  file. function test(){alert("test");} is my javascript function in send_notification.js file. I want to call function test() from appdelegate.m when app is brought from background to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  [self openNewViewController]; // read the userInfo from the payload and based on that open new controller
}`

method you can directly push/modal/addsubview your desired page.

And inside "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" check for remote notification payload

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        //Call your page here
    }
}
```

Comment: when your app will be in background i think you have to tap on Notification to reflect according to the notification payload. Not so sure.